# $_POST & Text-Transformation not interacted as expected

Tags: css

I'm using text-transformation=uppercase to make form input standard and I see that when I type in the field the first letter is capitalized. The problem is when I use _POST the cap is getting converted to lower case as seen in this sample from print_r:

> Array ( [FName_val] => john [LName_val] => stephen
>   [Equipment_Borrowed_val] => camera [Service_Tag_val] => 233222
>   [Borrwd_Rsn_val] => Borrowed [Date_Taken_val] => [Exp_Date_Return_val]
>   => [Comments_val] => )

Same thing happens with LName_val

HTML is:

```
 First Name:<input type="text" name="FName_val" maxlength="12" size="12"  placeholder="*" class="input_style" /><br /><br />

 Last Name:<input type="text" name="LName_val" maxlength="36" size="12" placeholder="*" class="input_style" /><br /><br />
```

CSS is:

```
.input_style[type=text], .input_style[type=date]  {
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #87CEFA;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #87CEFA;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #87CEFA;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #87CEFA;
    background-color:Ivory;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 165px;
    outline: none;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

This seems pretty straight forward but I cant figure it out. The same thing happens when I substitute some javascript I found on this site to do the same thing. Has anyone had this trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS does not modify the actual value of the input, you can use Javascript to capitalize the value before sending the data or preferably (since you can't expect everyone to have JS enabled) use PHP  to modify it once it gets to the server:

```
$_POST['FName_val'] = ucfirst($_POST['FName_val']);
```

Comment: Thanks but I just did a little php:

    $FName=ucfirst(strtolower($FName));
    $LName=ucfirst(strtolower($LName));
    $Eqpmnt_Brwd=ucfirst(strtolower($Eqpmnt_Brwd));

on the insert into MySQL after the _POST like koala_dev. Is there anyway to handle an input like Eddie VAN HALEN?

Comment: @alan you mean you want to capitalize each word? For that there's [`ucwords()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)

Answer (score 0):

CSS will just change the look , not the real data , you should use JS `toUpperCase()` Method.

check this fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/n7dadt8a/